# Dashboard Only Mode in Kibana 7.0.1

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, kibana-7

I am very new to ELK stack, and just exploring kibana, already created Dashboards and now when i share that Dashboard to others it shows all other tabs too in kibana instead it should be display only Dashboard.
how do i set such things in kibana?

I have installed kibana 7.1.0 on my computer, i am able to access directly using below link without login.
http://10.42.35.14:5601

I come to know that we can share kibana 7.1.0 dashboard using "Dashboard only mode" option but i dont know how to set it? which come security features under basic licence.
[image]

I have installed kibana on server and sharing Dashboard by clicking share option
Shared URL : [10.42.35.10:5601/goto/83d6947d72ae21a4d6ecccf27096b255](http://10.42.35.10:5601/goto/83d6947d72ae21a4d6ecccf27096b255)
[image]

Note: above ip is private, i shared kibana dashboard within my local network, but when i open shared link to other computer, i can see all the menus. it should be share only dashboard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you upgrade to 7.1.0, XPack Security is now included in the BASIC license, which means, it is free.

You can then configure your user with the [`kibana_dashboard_only_user`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/xpack-dashboard-only-mode.html) role and that user will not see all the features on the left.

Comment: I have upgraded to 7.1.0 but still "permission denied" while accessing http://localhost:5601/app/kibana#/management/security/users?_g=()

Comment: also tried to set setting in elasticsearch.yml file like xpack.license.self_generated.type: basic
xpack.security.enabled:true

Comment: also tried with kibana,yml with xpack.security.enabled:true

Comment: These comments don't belong to this question, right? You should delete them. Were you able to make it work?

Comment: already removed and tried but still getting same error ""permission denied" in security under management,

Comment: this question is about "desktop only" issue, not the "permission denied" one, right?

Comment: That's a private IP address ;-)

Comment: Are you logged in with the correct user who has the proper role?

Comment: there is no user, I am able to access elastic search and kibana without login. please read updated question.

Comment: but i suppose security feature is paid?

Comment: Read the first sentence of my answer again

Comment: Looks like in Kibana 7.9, this role/feature has been deprecated, and will be removed in Kibana 8.