# Remove/Hide Management Menu in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have setup Elasticsearch and Kibana 7.0.1 version. May I know how to hide or remove the Management menu from Kibana UI?

Comment: this answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56231941/4604579

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56231941/4604579), you can leverage the dashboard-only mode if you want to hide everything but dashboards.

Otherwise, since Kibana 7.2, you can go to Management > Spaces and decide to hide some Management features, such as:

- Advanced settings
- Index patterns management
- Saved objects management

Also worth noting that there's an [open issue](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/35965) to actually hide features based on cluster privileges.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The configuration of Kibana UI is received in the response to the `/{SPACE_URI}?api/core/capabilities` request. You can manipulate this response by putting Kibana behind a proxy ([mitmproxy](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/) is a quick/clean choice) and within the response set `body['navLinks']['kibana:management'] = False`. Then you won't see that management button on the sidebar anymore.

Answer (score 0):

After searching forever in Kibana 7.7.1, finally found that you can define what roles to include in the "Dashboard Only" mode under **Advanced Settings**.  Here you can define a second role to have dashboard only, AND NOT access to all spaces as the *kibana_dashboard_only_user* does.

[Advanced Settings --> Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EPFl.png)

Answer (score -2):

You can hide the management menu by clicking the **Collapse** button at the bottom of the menu.

[Collapse UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4N6v7.png)

I'm not so sure about removing it. Probably there is a more contextually appropriate solution for your concern, such as embedding a dashboard onto your app, or restricting management permissions to a certain group of users.

[dashboard-only-mode](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/xpack-dashboard-only-mode.html) may be of interest to you, and you can move up to minor version 7.1.0 in order to make this a free feature.

Comment: By any means this doesn't deserve to be an answer!